# How to convert a byte array to image in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, image, bitmap

How do I convert a byte array to an image in Node.js? I have tried the code below. It creates an image but when I open it, I get an error message

> Error interpreting JPEG image file.

I have converted the byte array from bitmap in Android and sent it to a Node server.

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

var fs = require('fs');

var bitmap = new Buffer(bytearray,'base64');

mkdirp(__dirname + "/images/",function(er)
{

  if(er) console.log(er);

  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/images/"+profile._id+".jpeg",bitmap);

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to store a bitmap as .jpg? shouldn't it be bmp?

Comment: at android side, have you created base64 string of image?

Comment: thank you for reply,i have created base64 string of image in android and send to node server,it created image successfully but, it not looks like how i sent,height and width of image has changed.

Comment: this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376410/byte-array-into-an-image-node-js

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608249/convert-base64-image-to-a-file-in-node-js?answertab=oldest#tab-top) worked fine for me.